# How to create listview on gridview using C# UWP?

Tags: c#, listview, gridview

I would like to create catalog where will be groups with lists. But I can't do this. Here is some example:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listview group in uwp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122502/listview-group-in-uwp)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know how to make a grouped listview, I think it has been answered on other threads as I mentioned in above comment.

If you think it's not very complete , you can follow the UWP official sample:[ListView and GridView sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView)

And if you also want to know how to make such UI interface, you need to start from [UWP style guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/index)

You should ask a specific question. The community members will not help you write all code to make such UI。