# Listview group in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app

I have a simple view with a `ListView`, I would like the `ListView`has two groups, a group for items with property `complete= 1` and another group with `complete= 0`.

This is my class:

```
public class myClass
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public bool complete{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my XML:

```
<ListView x:Name="MasterListView">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle >
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MasterListViewItemTemplate" x:DataType="model:myClass">
    <TextBlock Margin="0,5,5,5" Text="{x:Bind name}" FontSize="20" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I tried a few examples but I could not find anything.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2014/07/15/phone-listview-grouping

Comment: @Archana Will this work if ListView is child of PivotItem?

Comment: I guess so. It should work

Comment: @Archana Can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061480/grouping-listview-under-pivotitem-in-windows-10-uwp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I have a simple view with a ListView, I would like the ListViewhas two groups, a group for items with property complete= 1 and another group with complete= 0.

First, use a **CollectionViewSource** for content that presents a list of items that can be grouped or sorted.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" x:Name="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Then, get the data, group the data and **set the grouped data to the CollectionViewSource** in code behind.

Following is the sample code I have verified:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!--Use a collection view source for content that presents a list of items that can be grouped or sorted.-->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" x:Name="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView Background="White" Foreground="Black" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0.5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //Get the data
        List<MyClass> myClasses = new List<MyClass>();
        myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "A", Complete = false });
        myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "B", Complete = true });
        myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "C", Complete = true });
        myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "D", Complete = false });
        myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "E", Complete = true });
        myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "F", Complete = false });
        //Group the data
        var groups = from c in myClasses
                     group c by c.Complete;
        //Set the grouped data to CollectionViewSource
        this.cvs.Source = groups;
    }
}
```

Following is the output:
[image]