# Grouping ListView under PivotItem in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, grouping, windows-10-universal

I am currently working on grouping Listview based on billing_id in my case. I am proper able to retrieve group by items using GroupBy of LINQ, but I am facing issues while displaying it. It displays as an entire page and not as a child of PivotItem. My code is as the following.

First I created a **CollectionViewSource** in Page resources as follows

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" x:Name="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Then I retrieved all the list using GroupBy and assigned it to this CollectionViewSource as follows

```
var billingGroupByList = taskBillingList.GroupBy(b => b.billing_type_id).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
this.cvs.Source = billingGroupByList;
```

After that, I created UI including Grouping style and ItemTemplate as follows

```
<Pivot>
  <Pivot.Items>
     <PivotItem x:Name="ChargesPivot"
               Header="Charges"
               Background="White"
               Margin="0,-35,0,0">
          <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid Background="#F8F8FB" BorderBrush="#D6D6D6" BorderThickness="5,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="charges"
                                   Text="Charges"
                                   FontSize="18"
                                   Margin="10"
                                   Foreground="Gray"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ListView x:Name="chargesView"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GenericListViewContainerStyle}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"                          SelectionChanged="chargesView_SelectionChanged"
                              Margin="5">
                        <ListView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding billing_type}"
                                                   FontSize="16"
                                                   FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle>
                        </ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock x:Name="billing_date"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               Margin="4,1,4,4"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                               Text="{Binding Path = quantity}"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="charge"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               Margin="4,1,4,4"
                                               Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path = charge}"/>
                                        <Run Text=" "/>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path = charge_uom}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</PivotItem>
```

Can someone suggest, what I am doing wrong? This just display Charge as heading of the page and also makes my other UI of page has hidden. I just want to display this as just a part of a page.

I want to achieve similar to the following screenshot[image]

Comment: Where are  the pivot items?

Comment: `<PivotItem></PivotItem>` this one.

Comment: You have not posted that code. Please post full code

Comment: @Archana posted entire code. The output screenshot is just sample screenshot similar which I want to achieve.

Comment: Seems like you missed binding ItemSource of LIstView.  `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"`

Comment: I missed while editing post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that while your items are grouped, there is nothing to display for the group. If you look at your grouping:

```
var billingGroupByList = taskBillingList.GroupBy(b => b.billing_type_id)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
```

If you hover over `var` you'll see that the type of `billingGroupByList` is `List<List<BillingItem>>`. To display a "group header" you need an object with a property to display. Remove the Select portion of your linq and your object will be `List<IGrouping<int, BillingItem>>`. IGrouping has a `Key` property that you can then display in your group style.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine, I have `billing_type` in BillingItem object, how to use that in GroupStyle? I tried binding it but it shows empty. Can I use on `IGrouping Key` only in `HeaderTemplate`?

Comment: Are you grouping by billing_id or billing_type? Can you just group by billing_type?

Comment: Yes. I can do that.

Comment: If you can group by type, then the Key of IGrouping will be your billing_type property

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I was going on the right path, just made a minor mistake in using `List<List<Billing>>` instead of `IGrouping`. Thanks a lot for quick help. Just a quick question, can I remove the grey divider (Gray line)?